# How to find MSE based on observations from 2 samples.

Tags: variance, mean-square-error

I have 2 independent random samples: {$X_1, X_2$} and {$Y_1, Y_2...Y_{22}$} with E[$X_i$] = $\mu$  and E[$Y_j$] = $3\mu$, Var[$X_i$]= $\sigma^2$ and Var[$Y_j$]= $\sigma^2/2$.

Now I have the following **unbiased** estimator ->

$T_1$(**X,Y**) = $\frac{\bar X+\bar Y}{4}$.

I know that since it is unbiased it's MSE is just it's variance. I'm struggling to find the variance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the variance of $T_1(X,Y)$ we have,
\begin{align}
\text{Var}\left(\frac{\overline{X}+\overline{Y}}{4}\right) &= \frac{1}{16}\text{Var}(\overline{X}+\overline{Y}) = \frac{1}{16}\left(\text{Var}(\overline{X})+\text{Var}(\overline{Y}) + 2\text{Cov}(\overline{X},\overline{Y})\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{16}\left(\text{Var}(\overline{X})+\text{Var}(\overline{Y})\right)
\end{align}

Since, the two are independent. Then for the variances of the sample means we have,
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(\overline{X}) = \frac{1}{2}\text{Var}(X) = \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\\
\text{Var}(\overline{Y}) = \frac{1}{22}\text{Var}(Y) = \frac{\sigma^2}{44} \\
\end{align}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fixed a typo in the original answer.